# How to stop the individual programs that are specified in supervisord.conf file?

Tags: process, supervisord

I want to manage few process using supervisor.I have made the changes in the supervisord.conf file.I want to stop a few programs later

I tried using "supervisorctl stop program_name" command but I get the following

Sorry, supervisord responded but did not recognize the supervisor namespace commands that supervisorctl uses to control it.  Please check that the [rpcinterface:supervisor] section is enabled in the configuration file (see sample.conf).

Can somebody guide me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I had the same problem and found that [rpcinterface:supervisor] section has to be enabled. I followed model shown here :  https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/302#issuecomment-68080542 and it worked for me

Answer (score 21):

Add this to your /etc/supervisord.conf:

```
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface
```

And restart supervisord:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/supervisord restart
```