# supervisord refuses to run command as user (always runs as root)

Tags: python, django, supervisord

For some reason, supervisor refuses to start the `command` as `user` - it always runs it as root - and this is an issue for me since I am activating a `virtualenv` and running commands specific to that particulat virtualenv.

So, my conf looks like so:

```
[program:site]

command = /home/some/virtual/env/dir/run/start.sh
user = some
stdout_logfile = /home/some/etc/supervisor/logs/logging.log
redirect_stderr = true
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
stopsignal=KILL
killasgroup=true
autostart=true
```

start.sh looks like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $USER >> /home/some/user.txt
cd
source /home/foo/some/virtual/env/bin/activate
cd /home/foo/some/virtual/env
SOCKFILE01=/home/some/etc/supervisor/site.sock
exec /home/some/virtual/env/bin/gunicorn -b unix:$SOCKFILE01  site.wsgi:application -w 2 -k gevent --worker-connections=2000 
exit 0
```

when I inspect the log, I see:

```
start.sh: line 2: cd: /root: Permission denied
```

which means this is still running as root.

I am totally baffled by this. I start supervisor as root. The even weirder part is that the above code works totally fine on my local machine, but shows me the above log on a server.

I have run out of ideas... :((

EDIT:

added `echo` to the .sh script and user.txt spits out:

```
root
```

..totally puzzled!

Comment: Why don't you cd to /home/foo/some/virtual/env specifically?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I actually do that in start.sh - the problem is, when django starts, it expects some modules to reside within the virtual env directory (in this case `nltk_data`).. I do not understand why supervisor wouldnt run as the user?!?! - why is it still running as root?

Comment: @dhke: I know that supervisor is not running as user because it is expecting `nltk_data` directory in locations accesible only by `root`. Namely, it is searching for `nltk_data` in `/usr/share` etc - which requires root privileges. Also, when I do `echo $HOME` I get `/home/some` which is my username.

Comment: @dhke: Just to confirm, I added `echo $USER >> /home/some/user.txt`  to the .sh script .. and guess what I get? `root`!!

Comment: @dhke: please see `EDIT` in question

Comment: @JohnJ Environment variables aren't reliable, the output from `id` is a better indicator. But yes, it actually looks like the user switch doesn't work properly. Any selinux restrictions on the server?

Comment: To be honest it might be that home is not set properly, not that user stays as root, to be 100% sure I would touch a new file in the first line of start.sh and see who is the owner of mentioned file.

Comment: Of course my comment ignored that echo confirms first assesment. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the environment variables as below and update the command:

```
[program:site]

command=bash -c "/home/some/virtual/env/dir/run/start.sh"
user=some
stdout_logfile=/home/some/etc/supervisor/logs/logging.log
redirect_stderr=true
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8,HOME="/home/some",USER="some"
stopsignal=KILL
killasgroup=true
autostart=true
```

This is described in http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment and solved this issue for me when trying to run npm scripts.

Comment: Thanks very much. Note: I also had to add some `[rpcinterface:supervisor]` configuration. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36091300